# Rails: Changing date format displayed in date_field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, localization

I am working on a rails application and have changed the date format displayed across my app to `dd.mm.yyyy` using the following code in a file in the `config/initializers` directory:

```
Date::DATE_FORMATS[:default]="%d.%m.%Y"
Time::DATE_FORMATS[:default]="%d.%m.%Y %H:%M"
```

However, in my forms where I am using the `f.date_field` tags, the date display is shown as `mm/dd/yyyy`. How can I change the format used there?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
f.date_field :some_name, value: @some_time.strftime('%d.%m.%Y')
```

Comment: With this, how would I set it for an edit page so that it displays the currently saved date instead of now?

Comment: ```value: @some_formatted_time.strftime('%d.%m.%Y')```